# PHP variable scoping

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble with variable scoping in PHP. Here's the structure of my code--

```
<?php
$loader = new ELLoad();
$sessionid = '';
$method = $_REQUEST['m'];
if (strcasecmp($method, "getfile") == 0) {
    global $loader;
    $loader->load($file['text']);
    global $sessionid;
    $sessionid = $loader->getSessionId();
} 
if (strcasecmp($method, "extract") == 0) {
    $extractor = new ELExtract();
    global $sessionid;
    $extractor->extract($sessionid); //$session id for some reason is still ' ' here
}
```

The sequence of the requests from the client is always load followed by extract. Can anyone tell me why my $sessionid variable may not be getting updated right?

Comment: You don't need `global` within `if` statements, only within `function` calls. That and `global` is considered bad practice.

Comment: Why you are using `global` at first place? Variables are in global scope unless they are inside the function..

Comment: You do not need to use `global` keyword here. This keyword used when you are inside a e.g. `function`.

Comment: I removed all the 'global' keywords but I still get an empty sessionid in extract.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` after `$sessionid = $loader->getSessionId();` just to be sure that there's actually something in `$sessionid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declared `global $...` unless you're in a function. A block (if, while, ...) have the same scope than the line just before.

I don't know what you want to do, but you have to keep you `$sessionid` content in a real session, like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$loader = new ELLoad();
$_SESSION['id'] = '';
$method = $_REQUEST['m'];
if (strcasecmp($method, "getfile") == 0) {
    $loader->load($file['text']);
    $_SESSION['id']  = $loader->getSessionId();
} 
if (strcasecmp($method, "extract") == 0) {
    $extractor = new ELExtract();
    $extractor->extract($_SESSION['id']); //$session id for some reason is still ' ' here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sessionid` is still `''`, because It's not change if `first condition` == `false`

**Improvement of your code:**

```
$loader = new ELLoad();
$sessionid = $loader->getSessionId();
$method = $_REQUEST['m'];
if (strcasecmp($method, "getfile") == 0) {
    $loader->load($file['text']);
    // do more stuff
}
else if (strcasecmp($method, "extract") == 0) {
    $extractor = new ELExtract();
    $extractor->extract($sessionid);
    // do more stuff
}
```

Also It's better to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` depend on your case, instead of `$_REQUEST` and finally using `else if` in separate and repeated conditions.